# Is it wrong to talk about current moving fast?

Tags: electric-current, terminology

This is a question regarding terminology.

Current is the rate of flow of charge.

I always say current increases/decreases or current gets higher/lower.

I recently heard someone telling their students that they shouldn't say current gets faster/slower, rather that charges get faster/slower.

However, I am not sure whether saying current gets faster is entirely incorrect. For example, I think it's OK to say current travels at a slower speed than light. But I am not sure if it is wrong or imprecise to do.

What is the opinion here?

Answer (score 2):

At a minimum it is potentially confusing to talk about a fast current.

From the perspective of Maxwell’s equations there is no difference between a given current density and a current density produced by twice the charge carrier density moving at half the speed (assuming both are accompanied by an equal and opposite stationary charge density). As long as the current density is the same the resulting fields will be the same.

So the idea of fast or slow current, while it could probably be made physically unambiguous, it would have no physical importance.